The good way to restore an abandoned 3 years old Flutter project?
I am a beginner in Flutter and Dart.
Recently, I was introduced in a new project : restore a 3 years old flutter project. No commits have been made for 3 years
All dependancies are in an old obsolete version (no one has been null safety) - or deprecated -, Flutter and the Dart SDK are update since 3 years.
My problem : How I can "upgrade" this project correctly ? Is there a good way/method to "migrate" an old project to the most recent update of the Dart SDK/Flutter and his dependancies ?
First, I upgrade, replace and remove all the dependancies that needed (dependancies without null safety) and launch the command flutter pub upgrade --major-versions. The result of this was 1000 errors in the code due to changing, deleting and updating dependencies.
During my research, I found the command dart migrate, but it was removed in Dart 3.
I don't know if I take the good way to restore this Flutter project. I want to know if there is a better method to do that (obviously, I launch the command dart fix --apply, it has fixed some minor errors).
Thanks in advance for answers !

you use 2/3 sdk version to update the project, 1st enable null-safety, then move to the current version, yap it will be a tedious work.

Yes, I already enable null-safety on the project. Now my job is to fix these 1000 errors. If I have to deal with all the errors one by one, it will be a REALLY tedious job. There's really no way to migrate everything from this old version to the newer version quickly ? If there really isn't, I accept my fate.
Thank you for your anwser !

There are many stuffs has been removed, so I am not aware of any better way

Yes indeed.
Thank you for your help.

Get familiar with the changelogs, especially the breaking changes.

I have a video about using puro to first install the version that can do dart migrate, then upgrade after that to the current version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olqmK-opexA

For the migration to null safety, I recommend you use the interactive migration tool offered through the dart migrate command.
https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migration-tool
And in general, I recommend you to read the whole page there, there's really useful information and hints on how to do exactly what you are trying to do :)
To add to that, as mentioned on that page you should use Dart 2.19.6 to run the migration tool, and once migrated upgrade to the next version. This will likely also mean upgrading to 'intermediate' versions of your dependencies that still support this Dart version.
As the other commenters said already, it'll be quite tedious, but hopefully the tool can help a bit

Okay, thank you. I'll try it again. It's possible I used a wrong version of Dart.

Okay, finally I try to used this command but it's impossible because the previous persons before me who was touch the code was very incompetent and all packages are conflicts with there dependancies so it's impossible to launch this command. But it's in theory, this command works, just in my case it won't launch because the dependancies.
Thanks a lot for answers guys !
